# How do I select a Right Click Menu Item on Browser Menu with Protractor/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, menu, protractor, right-click

I am trying to select "Back" after performing a Right Click. I can get the Right-Click menu.  I am getting an error when I try to select "Back".
Here is the code:

```
browser.driver.findElement(By.linkText("Back")).click();
```

I am using Chrome browser on MAC-OS.

Here is the error:

> Message:  NoSuchElementError: no such element  (Session info:
>   chrome=43.0.2357.130)  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457
>   (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Mac OS X 10.10.3
>   x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information) Command duration or timeout: 23 milliseconds

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: right-click is not a web thing..  just don't.

Comment: Show how do you perform the right click and the HTML structure of the menu.

Comment: @alecxe  I am trying to get to the browsers' right-click menu to select 'Back'.   Here is the code:                                                                                          'browser.driver.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform(); // For doing right click on mouse.
browser.driver.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ARROW_DOWN).perform(); //To send arrow down.
browser.driver.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform(); // To send enter.'  Found this code on Stackoverflow.        -Lyle

Answer (score 0):

You can use following jQuery code to detect ***Right Mouse Click***

```
$('#element').mousedown(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 1:
            alert('Left Mouse button pressed.');
            break;
        case 2:
            alert('Middle Mouse button pressed.');
            break;
        case 3:
            alert('Right Mouse button pressed.');
            break;
        default:
            alert('You have a strange Mouse!');
    }
});
```

And that you can call following code to perform *back button action* (or go to lastly visited page)

```
window.history.back();
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: What I am trying to do is get the browser menu to appear and select different items on the browser menu that appear.  I need because it interacts with the app.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that you are trying to click on the menu before it appears.

```
var driver = browser.driver,
 wd = browser.wd,
 until = wd.until,
 elementToRightClick = driver.findElement(wd.By.linkText('foo'));
 driver.actions().click(elementToRightClick,wd.Button.RIGHT).perform(); 
 driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(driver.findElement(wd.By.linkText('back')),5000, 'Element back was not visibile');
 driver.findElement(wd.By.linkText('back')).click();
```

Comment: Thanks but, the code above did not work.  The issue is that 'back' is not found.

Comment: I had a typo earlier in the wait. Edit it now. Does your right click work at all and are you sure the selector for back is correct?

Comment: The right click does work.  I see the menu.  Will try your edited code.  Will let you know what happens.  Thanks !!